# maps api v3 best way to bind info window and links?

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

trying to figure out the best way to do this but can't seem to find anything useful.  user comes to my site and runs query to find restaurants in their area.  it plots markers to the map and outputs a list to the side of the map of each returned result in a search result div.  the div list is about 300 pixels in height, so if the results are any more, it becomes scrollable.  so user can scroll up and down the list if many results.

How can I get it so that if a user clicks a link of a location on the list, that it opens up the corresponding info window on the map?  additionally, how could I get it so that if a user clicks a marker on the map, that it scrolls to the location link on the left side search result div?

thanks for suggestions, examples, or links to tutorials!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the docs.

Here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows